# How to change email status google api c#

Tags: asp.net, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am following code to mark unread email as read in my Gmail using Google API C# Code. This is the code

but I am getting the following error:

Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Insufficient Permission [403] Errors [Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]]

How to resolve this issue for Gmail reading using Google API C#

Comment: "insufficientPermissions" - you need to look at the documentation to see what permissions you need to perform that action,

Comment: I have already read some documentation . But i did not get proper way to solve this issue

Comment: could you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

[Messages.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) method allows you to make changes to the message. You need to modify the message and remove the UNREAD label.  The message will then appear to be read

```
public static Message ModifyMessage(GmailService service, String userId,
      String messageId, List<String> labelsToAdd, List<String> labelsToRemove)
  {
      ModifyMessageRequest mods = new ModifyMessageRequest();
      mods.RemoveLabelIds = "UNREAD";

      try
      {
          return service.Users.Messages.Modify(mods, userId, messageId).Execute();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
      }

      return null;
  }
```

**Not on access**

This method requires one of the following scopes of access

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify

Comment: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Insufficient Permission [403] Errors [Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]]